# How to avoid NoClassDefFoundError with different Android API versions

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm developing an application for APIs from v10 to v17.

My activity implements OnDragListener which is available only from API v14.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnDragListener {
    ....
}
```

So, when application is installed on device with API v10 it fails to load activity with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

I understand that this won't work on API v10, that's OK. I'm handling this inside the activity.

I just want to know What is the practice to handle different API versions when it comes to features like this?

Comment: int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO){} else{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can check API levels and depending on that to execute or not your code. For example :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
     // don't use it.
} else {
     // use the new API :
     // myView.setOnDragListener(...);
}
```

You should not implement interfaces from new API's in Activity if you want to support old android versions too. Instead of that use the approach above.

Comment: You can implement the interfaces, but not in the Activities - otherwise they will not be loadable on older devices.

Comment: That's what I am saying.You can implement the interface in `else` part of my example or in another class, but doing that in Activity will throw that exception in old versions. That's why in my opinion the best option to fix that is just to check API levels and use the new API's depending on that. At least that's the way I am doing it in my apps.

Comment: I completely agree. I posted my comment because I wanted to clarify on your answer. With your comment now it is complete :)

Comment: I saw now I forgot to mention not to implements the interfaces from new API's in Activities, thanks for the comment and attention! : )

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should not declare the activity to implement `View.OnDragListener`. Just do the logic in another class and instantiate it only when you need it (I suppose you add the listener only for API >= 14).